# Bash script to open executable in a new terminal

Tags: macos, bash, makefile

My intent is to automate the compilation process in my workflow. I have a single `Makefile` in the root directory and I find myself constantly typing in `make` to see the result and then `SIGTERM` to refresh (I'm running OS X 10.8.5). Whereas ideally, a bash script would listen for changes in the file, and automake when they are made, and then run the executable.

I have the following attempt at implementing a bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
    ATIME=`stat library/grid.c | egrep -o -m 3 '"(.{20})"' | tail +4`

    if [[ "$ATIME" != "$LTIME" ]]
    then
        echo "Running make..."
        bash -e make; ./sheet
        LTIME=$ATIME
    fi
    sleep 1
done
```

This results in the following errors

```
/usr/bin/make: /usr/bin/make: cannot execute binary file
./listener.sh: line 10: ./sheet: No such file or directory
```

How do I issue the command to make and run an executable in a new terminal window? The point of this is that I can keep my bash script running, listening for changes in the background, without the executable taking over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not legal to run `bash -e <cmd>` for any command, not just make.  The argument given to `bash` is expected to be a *shell script*, not a program.

I don't know why you're trying to use a shell like that; why not just run `make` directly?  But if you really want to run `make` in bash you'll have to use the `-c` flag.

If what you want to do is stop your script if make fails, then use:

```
make || exit 1
./sheet
```

If you want to keep going after an error but not run the command, then use:

```
make && ./sheet
```

Comment: I think he was trying to use that to get a new terminal window not realizing that his shell and his terminal are not the same thing.